# Transfering ArrayList values to another ArrayList but with each value are concatenated with String

Tags: java, android, arraylist

So I have here two ArrayLists; `arrayList1` and `arrayList2`. What I want to happen is all the values from `arrayList1` will be concatenated with `String` one-by-one and copied to `arrayList2`.

Here are values of my arraylists:

---

`arrayList1` = `Harry, Larry, Sally, Molly, Karrie`

Now the result I want to be saved on `arrayList2` looks like this:

`Harry and, Larry and, Sally and, Molly and, Karrie`

---

Notice that every items except that last one was concatenated with `and`. How can I possibly achieve this? Thanks :)

Comment: I don't know  how to implement the loop in this situation though, I've been thinking about that earlier but ends up asking here.

Comment: The code below should work, you can use that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple as this :

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList2 = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i=0; i<arrayList1.size() - 1; i++) {
        String s = arrayList1.get(i) + "and";
        arrayList2.add(s);
}
```

Comment: Great! But it seems it will not return the last value so I'll just modify it